# How to loop through all nodes in XML and change node value based on its value in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, regex

```
   <result>
        <relatedProducts>
        <item>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <text></text>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <text></text>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <text></text>
        </item>
        ...
        </relatedProducts>
        <item>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <intro></intro>
            <detail></detail>
        </item>
            <item>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <intro></intro>
            <detail></detail>
        </item>
        ... 
    </result>
```

This is a simplified XML structure of the xml file I want to use.

There are might be website urls inside the node text, e.g.

```
<text>...href="something.com/default.aspx?id=3"...</text>

<detail>...href="something.com/default.aspx?id=25"...</detail>
```

What I want is in C# loop through all the nodes in this xml document and check the URL link, then change the link based on the id in that link. For example,

I use regular expression to check every node value I see this URL meet the pattern

```
<text>...href="something.com/default.aspx?id=3"...</text>
```

And I'd like to change it to

```
<text>...href="somethingelse.com/query.aspx?rid=3"...</text>
```

At last, return the whole xml document with the right URL.

Comment: "How can I do it?" - you've already provided the solution in your question. Load the XML file. Recurse through all nodes. Update the node values using a regex. Save the result. What part do you need help with? (We can't develop the whole application for you.)

Comment: If all you're interested in is finding the URLs, it may not even be worth treating it as an XML file, just read each line in at a time and see if there's a URL there.  If there is, transform it and write the line back to a new file.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I encounter another problem which is how to replace the URLs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994105/c-search-and-replace-multiple-urls-in-a-string

Comment: @dtb I knew the pseudo code, but I had problem to implement it, that's why I ask the question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
foreach(var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    element.Value = ReplaceUrl(element.Value);
}
doc.Save(path);
```

I'll let you implement the `ReplaceUrl` method, since I don't know exactly what you need to do... Just a few general suggestions:

- you could use regular expressions to extract the URL from the element text (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url))
- the easiest way to parse and modify the URL is probably to use the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class, which allows you to access the individual components of the URL (scheme, host, path, query string...)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I encounter another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994105/c-search-and-replace-multiple-urls-based-on-the-value-in-the-url     I appreciate it if you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim xmlNodeList As XmlNodeList
    Dim xmlNode As XmlNode

    xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML)
    'xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("text")'Do this if its a particular tag
    xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("result")'Or just put the root tag, in my   
                                                       'case result was the root tag

    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
        xmlNode.InnerText = "new text"
    Next
```

Search for the particular tag and then do a replace.

Comment: They aren't all `text` elements (see example)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Of course Thomas's solution would be more effective.